# Hyper-V CentOS 7 guest slow/hangs after live migration

Tags: hyper-v, centos7, windows-server-2016, confluence

I have *one* guest machine, out of dozens, running CentOS 7 and Confluence that will run very slow after a live migration, and then hang up completely after a second live migration. (We're shipping machines around to run Windows Updates and reboot the hosts.) Once it's hung up, I have to force a reset to bring it back online.

It's only running Confluence and nginx for reverse proxy, for under 50 users. The MySQL database is running on another host, as well as JIRA (and its nginx rp) on separate host as well. The guest otherwise runs fine. Memory usage is low, CPU usage is low, disk activity is low. Everything is up to date on software patches (latest CentOS pages, latest Confluence install, latest Windows Updates).

I'm having a hard time finding anything relevant with any other searches here or on the interwebs.

What can I look for that might help me diagnose this problem? Is this at all common?

Comment: I would expect the problems with virtual disk. Hyper v is not very stable in my opinion, and you should probably go out this platform.

Comment: The disk is a Cluster Shared Volume on a SAN over 4x 1Gbps link per host. (Unfortunately) we migrated from VMware to Hyper-V last year, and I don't see us going back any time soon.

Comment: I mean not problem with shared volume, but with hyper v virtual vhdx disk and specially with delta files etc related to live migration